# How to create a topology diagram using Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to create a topology (network) diagram, which will be integrated with my `extJS` application. Is anyone familiar with some Javascript packages with APIs for creating such a diagram, taking care of: positioning the nodes in the diagram, zooming, and dragging the nodes?

In addition I want to use some custom icons for the nodes in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into yEd/yFiles (https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)  It's Java, not JavaScript, but it will definitely run as an applet since it does so from their site as a demo.  Might work if this is for an intranet to just embed it in the middle of an ExtJS panel.  Otherwise I recommend you read and re-read the drag and drop API for ExtJS and review the source code for them as well if you intend to code it yourself.  Also from a google search:

https://github.com/jgraph  (commercial)

https://www.jointjs.com/   (MIT Licenses)