# REST Client application with Topology diagram

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, topology

I suppose to develop a network management REST client with topology diagram (as an image showing below). With that application, the user should able to create a topology diagram by drag and drop, change the nodes positions by dragging, edit nodes properties and delete node elements.

Now I'm doing some feasibility study how can I approach this task with HTML 5 client or Java thick client. I have seen some API called [esri](https://www.esri.com/en-us/home) but it is commercialised.

I have planned to develop this application Angularjs or JavaFX. But none of them has inbuild libraries for it (I'm more preferring to develop this client application with AngularJs). Could you please help me to find any JavaScript frameworks or Java libraries available for accomplishing this task (then I can integrate them with AngularJs or JavaFX).

I have seen similar kind of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398572/how-to-create-a-topology-diagram-using-javascript) at StackOverflow, it was too old but now it can be available new frameworks.

Thanks

[image: Topology diagram]

Comment: Have you checked D3.js or Cytoscape?

Comment: @aurelienshz - no I'll check, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can be accomplishing this task with some HTML 5 related UI frameworks which can visualize interactive graphs (user can create, update, read, and delete the graph elements). Some of them are as follow,

- GoJS

[GoJS](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html) is a feature-rich JavaScript library for implementing custom interactive diagrams and complex visualizations across modern web browsers and platforms. 
The library makes constructing JavaScript diagrams of complex nodes, links, and groups easy with customizable templates and layouts.
Commercial license.

[image]

source: https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/SnapLinkReshaping.html

- JointJS

[JointJS](https://www.jointjs.com/) is a modern HTML 5 JavaScript library for visualization and interaction with diagrams and graphs.
It can be used to create either static diagrams or, and more importantly, fully interactive diagramming tools such as workflow editors, 
process management tools, IVR systems, API integrators, presentational applications and more. Licensed under both Open Source license (fewer features) and Commercial license (more features).

[image]

source: https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/kitchensink

- mxGraph

[mxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/) is a JavaScript diagramming library that enables interactive graph and charting applications to be quickly created that run natively in any major browser. 
Under the Apache license 2.0 (free and open source).
Support for JavaScript, Java, .NET, and PHP.

1) *mxDraw*

[image]

source: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html

2) *Graph Editor*

[image]

source: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html

- vis.js

[vis.js](http://visjs.org/) is a dynamic, browser-based visualization library. 
The library is designed to be easy to use, to handle large amounts of dynamic data, and to enable manipulation of and interaction with the data.
Licensed under both Apache 2.0 (free and open source) and MIT (open source license).

[image]

source: vis.js [library](https://github.com/almende/vis/archive/v4.20.1.zip)

- D3.js

[D3.js](https://d3js.org/) is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. 
D3 brings data to life using HTML, SVG, and CSS. D3’s emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern browsers,
combining powerful visualization components and a data-driven approach to DOM manipulation. 
Under the BSD license (open source initiative).

[image]

source: http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

**Conclusion**

According to the features of GoJS, it is the most convenient framework for visualizing interactive graphs, 
because UI can customize easily and can save the Diagram Model as JSON format. 
But this is under the commercial license ($2995 per developer).

JointJS provides fewer features with their open source license version, 
therefore needs to purchase the commercial version for fulfilling our requirements.
It may be difficult to customize their complex UI.

D3.js is more user-friendly but we have to proceed more effort to fine-tune it according to our requirements such as, 
proceed the node creation via a tool icon, enable the user to customize the node’s caption value, remove some existing visual effects, etc.
Needs to explore about the saving format (JSON, XML, TXT, etc.) of Diagram Model.

According to my conclusion, we can choose either mxGraph or vis.js JavaScript library for our developments.

**mxGraph**: It seems we can easily customize the ‘mxDraw’  (web 2.0-style diagram editor) drawing application and reuse it.
   ‘Graph Editor’ diagram editor application is more advanced and it may take more time to customize it and needs to explore about the Diagram Model saving format.

**vis.js**: Is more user-friendly than ‘mxGraph’ but we may have to spend some development effort for exploring about Diagram Model saving format and removing existing visual effects.